# PHP Regex - Remove text from HTML Tags

Tags: php, regex

How to remove all text between tags.

Input

```
<div>
    <p>testing</p>
    <div>my world</div>
</div>
```

Output

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [**DOMDocument**](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) or [**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
The following example uses the latter, although you may want to use what suits you best.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$str = '
<div>
    <p>testing</p>
    <div>my world</div>
</div>
';

$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("text") as $ht) {
   $ht->innertext = "";
}
$html->save();
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two capture groups which would eliminate characters between them while replacing:

```
(\<.+\>).*(\<\/.+\>)
```

working example: http://ideone.com/Oq14El